# Cannot convert value of type '<Int>' to expected element type <Any>

Tags: swift, generics, types, swiftui, swift3

I'm trying to learn swift, but I have a problem where using <Object> in Java would fix my problem I think, and the Apple doc says I should use <Any> but I keep getting errors.

I'm trying to build a memorize card game, I have the following models:

Theme.swift <- In charge of modeling different kind of themes for the cards, the idea is that the cards could have numbers, images etc, thats why it has a generic type after the name

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Theme<Type> {
    
    internal init(name: String, emojis: [Type], numberOfPairs: Int, cardsColor: UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.emojis = emojis
        if(numberOfPairs > emojis.count || numberOfPairs < emojis.count) {
            fatalError("Index out of bounds")
        }
        self.numberOfPairs = numberOfPairs
        self.cardsColor = cardsColor
    }
    
    var name: String
    var emojis: [Type]
    var numberOfPairs: Int
    var cardsColor: UIColor
    
}
```

I also have a Game model in charge of the game logic and cards model, I still have to implement a lot of stuff, but here's the code

```
import Foundation

struct Game {
    
    var themes: [Theme<Any>]
    var cards: [Card<Any>]
    var score = 0
    var isGameOver = false
    var choosenTheme: Theme<Any>
    
    init(themes: [Theme<Any>]) {
        self.themes = themes
        self.choosenTheme = self.themes.randomElement()!
        cards = []
        for index in 0..\<choosenTheme.numberOfPairs {
            cards.append(Card(id: index*2, content: choosenTheme.emojis[index]))
            cards.append(Card(id: index*2+1, content: choosenTheme.emojis[index]))
        }
    }
    
   
    mutating func endGame() {
        isGameOver = true
    }
    
    mutating func penalizePoints() {
        score -= 1
    }
    
    mutating func awardPoints () {
        score += 2
    }
    
    
    
    struct Card<T>: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var isFaceUP: Bool = false
        var content: T
        var isMatchedUP: Bool = false
        var isPreviouslySeen = false
    }
    
}
```

As you can notice I've used the Any type for creating an array of Cards and themes, cuz they could have strings, numbers or images

In my ViewModel I have the following code, where I'm trying to fill the Array of themes with two themes, one of string type of content, and the other one of Int:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class GameViewModel {
    
    static let halloweenTheme = Theme<Int>(name: "WeirdNumbers", emojis: [1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 30], numberOfPairs: 6, cardsColor: .darkGray)
    static let emojisTheme = Theme<String>(name: "Faces", emojis: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], numberOfPairs: 5, cardsColor: .blue)
    
    var gameController: Game = Game(themes: [halloweenTheme, emojisTheme])
    
    
}
```

But I keep getting this or a similar error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Theme<Int>' to expected element type
> 'Array<Theme<Any>>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Theme<Any>')
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'Theme<String>' to expected element type
> 'Array<Theme<Any>>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Theme<Any>')

And my mind is going crazy, I thought that by using [Theme<Any>] I would be able to have an array like this: [Theme<String>, Theme<Int>, Theme<Image>, ...] but it looks like not

Does anybody have a clue of what is going on here?

Comment: Generis are not covariant. `Theme<Any>` is not related to `Theme<Int>` at all.

Comment: @vadian What does that mean? Isn't an Int of type Any? In Java and Int would be of type Object, so what can I do instead?

Comment: `Any` can be cast to `Int` but `Theme<Any>` and `Theme<Int>` are completely different types. You can create a wrapper struct as suggested in the Quinn's answer.

Comment: Why use generics at all when it only defines the content of an array and you want that array to contain different types (which is a bad idea in itself)? You might as well declare the array property to be `[Any]` directly and skip generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper struct, basic example below. Note: if you need conformance to Codable, you need to implement encode/decode on your own.

```swift
struct Values<A> {
   let value: A
}

struct Wrapper {
   let wrappedValue: Values<Any>
}

class MyClass {
   var wrappedValues: [Wrapper] = [Wrapper(wrappedValue: Values(value: "hello")), Wrapper(wrappedValue: Values(value: 1))]
}
```